# Matlab rank function bug

Tags: matlab, rank

How come Matlab returns 6 when asking for the rank of an identity matrix of size 7?

```
rank(eye(7))
```

apparently there has to be more text here for me to be able to post the question.
Thanks

Comment: I doubt that there is a bug in this two functions... Please try again running `clear` before your line of code. If this does not help, edit your question to include the results of the following two commands: `which rank` and `which eye`.

Comment: What version are you using? I tried your command on R2015a and it returned 7.

Comment: I am using version 2014a. Its the rank function that comes with that Matlab version. Looking at the code I see that it's using the line s = svds(A); and inside svds, there is this: if nargin < 2
   k = min(p,6);
else. I have never touched these functions.

Comment: In version R2014b `rank` uses `svd` and not `svds`. I have no source to check what would be correct in R2014a. What I can tell is, that when I replace `svd` with `svds`, the result is `6`, too. So it probably is the right place to search. The `min(p,6)`-line has nothing to do with that *odd* behaviour of `rank` in your case.

Comment: of course it does (why else would I put it here?) setting this to min(p,7) changes the result to 7. I guess, ill just change the function to use svd then. Btw, to all those downvoters: before downvoting questions like this one you might want to take a moment to think about whether they may have merit. Don't be so over-confident to assume the person asking the question must be making some stupid mistake.

Comment: This is weird because I have 2013b on work computer and `rank` on mine also uses `svd` not `svds`.

Comment: Cannot reproduce.  I have MATLAB R2013 and `rank(eye(7))` gives 7 as expected.  `rank` also uses `svd` under the hood.  If your function is using `svds`, simply replace with `svd`.  `svds` finds fewer singular values... by default that's 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rank` in matlab 2014a uses `svd`, not `svds`. If your local file uses `svds` the installation is corrupted. I recommend to reinstall Matlab and set write restrictions to the toolbox folder afterwards to prevent such problems happen again.